# What is the proper way of assigning values to object attributes in Python?

Tags: python, class

I am a complete Python novice so my question might seem to be dumb. I've seen there are two ways of assigning values to object attributes in Python:

Using `__dict__`:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.__dict__['a'] = a
        self.__dict__['b'] = b
```

Without `__dict__`:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Can anyone explain where is the difference?

Comment: The second way is better.

Comment: There is not much difference except that the second one is shorter and clearer (thus more pythonic).

Comment: Another problem with `__dict__` approach is that it'll also allow you to create attributes like `'a  b'`, but then you can't access such attributes without using `__dict__` because `a  b` is an invalid variable name in python.

Comment: If you're new just ignore any mention if `__dict__`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you need set attributes dynamically and bypass [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) or the [`.__setattr__()` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), do not assign attributes directly to `.__dict__`.

Not all instances *have* a `.__dict__` attribute even, not if the class defined a [`.__slots__` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to save memory.

If you do need to set attributes dynamically but don't need to bypass a descriptor or a `.__setattr__()` hook, you'd use the [`setattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) normally.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Both class types (new-style classes) and class objects
>   (old-style/classic classes) are typically created by class definitions
>   (see section Class definitions). A class has a namespace implemented
>   by a dictionary object. Class attribute references are translated to
>   lookups in this dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]`
>   (although for new-style classes in particular there are a number of
>   hooks which allow for other means of locating attributes).

The much more typical way of assigning a new element to a class is your second example, which allows for a number of customizations (`__seattr__`, `__getattr__`, etc.).